# Creating a Statistical Information using textfiles. (Python)

Tags: python

i am currently creating a vaccination program as my assignment. The last Question requires me to print out total number of patients vaccinated by each VC (vaccination center). And the numbers should be broken down into people who are waiting for dose 2 (as some vaccine require dose 2) and people have completed vaccination. It is asked that i retrieve the information from a textfile.

So let's say in my textfile, the patient's information looks like this:

```
VC1 (vaccination center)
Dominic
18 (age)
AZ (vaccine) (needs two dose)
D1 completed (first dose completed)
D2 completed (second dose completed)
```

How should i create the algorithm for it?

Comment: Are you trying to read the text file into some other data format (e.g. data table)?

Comment: Don't really matter. Just have to show

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague. I'm trying to ask what you actually want to achieve. What is your desired outcome?

Comment: I actualy have no idea, how to do it.

Comment: My desired outcome is to print how many people have each VC vaccinated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for one record there will be always 6 rows instead of 6 columns, you can read all lines and divide it by 6 so you will get number of record of people who are vaccinated. Such as:

```py
with open('vaccine_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    vac_people_count = len(lines) // 6
    print(vac_people_count)
```

In my opinion your text file is not formatted well and can be chaged something similar to this:

```
VC1,name,age,AZ,D1,D2
A Place,Dominic,24,2,completed,completed
...
```

In this way you can manipulate every record easier and create more complex logics.

```py
with open('vaccine_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    vac_people_count = 0
    for line in file:
        datas = line.split(',')
        # do your custom work such as people count
        if datas[-1] == "completed" and datas[-2] == "completed":
            vac_people_count += 1
    print(vac_people_count)
```

Comment: thank you, I will look into it and determine how to draw out my own.

Comment: No problem, if any answer is useful or the worked for you, you can upvote or approve those answers, you can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)